# mosaicking rasters in R

Tags: raster, r, mosaic

What is the unit of argument "tolerance" used in mosaic {raster}? Is it pixel or raster unit?

```
x <- srtm_v4.1_90m
names(x)[1:2] <- c('x', 'y')
x$fun <- mean
x$na.rm <- TRUE
x$tolerance = 0.5
```

I am trying to mosaic srtm tiles using following script but I am not sure about unit of argument "tolerance" used in the script.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation says:

```
tolerance: Numeric. permissible difference in origin (relative to the
          cell resolution). See ‘all.equal’
```

which would make me think that `tolerance=0.01` would mean 1/100 of the raster resolution.

Let's dig into the source code:

https://github.com/cran/raster/blob/master/R/mosaic.R#L15

takes the value passed to `mosaic` and passes it through to `compareRaster`. The help for `compareRaster` says:

```
tolerance: numeric between 0 and 0.5. If not supplied, the default
          value is used (see ‘rasterOptions’. It sets difference
          (relative to the cell resolution) that is permissible for
          objects to be considered 'equal', if they have a non-integer
          origin or resolution. See all.equal.
```

The code for `compareRaster` does this when testing if two objects have the same extent:

```
if (!(isTRUE(all.equal(ext1, extent(objects[[i]]), tolerance=tol, scale=minres ))))
```

where `minres` is the smallest resolution value over x and y over rasters being compared. This `all.equal` test is therefore working as documented, and testing for equality relative to the tolerance as a fraction of resolution, or cell size.